# whitespace-style "face" activates highlighting of quoted string in fundamental mode

Tags: whitespace, whitespace-mode

After putting `face` to `whitespace-style`:

```lisp
(setq whitespace-style '(trailing tabs empty face))
(global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

string enclosed in a double quote started to be highlighted by `font-lock-string-face` in fundamental-mode.

As workaround I disabled `global-whitespace-mode` and switched to old good v21.1 style:

```lisp
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
(set-face-attribute 'trailing-whitespace nil :background "magenta")
```

Still I like `whitespace-mode` goodies. It is a bug? How can I debug an issue with double quotation highlighting?

**EXTRA** When problem is here `font-lock-keywords` has value:

```lisp
(t
 ((whitespace-point--flush-used)
  (#1="\\(  +\\)" . #2=(1 whitespace-tab t))
  (whitespace-trailing-regexp . #3=(1 whitespace-trailing t))
  (whitespace-empty-at-bob-regexp . #4=(1 whitespace-empty t))
  (whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp . #5=(1 whitespace-empty t)))
 (whitespace-point--flush-used
  (0 nil))
 (#1# #2#)
 (whitespace-trailing-regexp #3#)
 (whitespace-empty-at-bob-regexp #4#)
 (whitespace-empty-at-eob-regexp #5#))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do it. It's source is from `font-lock.el` which is included in emacs.

```lisp
(setq font-lock-string-face nil)
```

Comment: Interesting, but I have to make `font-lock-string-face` buffer local based on complicated condition + highlighting engine still works under the hood. I need this for large log files so it is not particularly suitable workaround for my case... I think I have to report bug...